# "Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader webpack error

Tags: webpack

webpack version - 2.3.2

node version -4.6.1

Ii am getting this strange error

```
    /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:35
                        throw new Error("Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)");
                        ^

Error: Module '/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/file/lib/file.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)
    at loadLoader (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:35:10)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:179:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:268:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:142:10)
```

I checked the github questions and answers. Looks like I need to add -loaders in all the used loaders. But, I am already using -loaders. Check out my webpack config

```
    var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: {app: './src/app.js' },
  output: {filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, loader: 'babel-loader',options: {
        presets: ['stage-0','react','es2015'],
        plugins: ["transform-decorators-legacy","transform-class-properties"]
    } },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
      { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'  },
   {
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[sha512:hash:hex].[ext]'
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        bypassOnDebug: true,
        mozjpeg: {
          progressive: true
        },
        gifsicle: {
          interlaced: true
        },
        optipng: {
          optimizationLevel: 7
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
    ]
  }
}
```

There is no other thread on stackoverflow which solves this issue. Thats why I have to open a new thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
{ test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' }
```

You have a module called [`file`](https://github.com/aconbere/node-file-utils) installed, that Webpack is trying to load. Because it's not a loader, you're getting the error (AFAIK, with any loader configuration, Webpack will always first try to load the module by name verbatim, so `file` in this case, and only when the module doesn't exist will it retry by appending `-loader`, so `file-loader`; however, since `file` exists, Webpack thinks is has found the correct loader module).

Change it to this:

```
{ test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are encountering similar problem, please note that `webpack2` needs all the name of `loaders`  to have a suffix of `-loader`.

So a loader named `url` shall have to used as `url-loader` as shown below.

```
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?/,
  loader: 'url-loader'
}
```

Another example..

```
{test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader"},
```